# How can I produce a result with various inputs by machine learning?

Tags: r, machine-learning

I've been studying machine learning in R and wondered how machine learning algorithms can produce a new result with new inputs. For example, in Iris data, there are 4 features (Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width) with values and its Species type (sentosa, versicolor, virginia).

We use the given data to build models to learn, predict and check if it was a suitable model. But what if there is a new set of data but don't know what the Species is? For example, how would I know what the Species is if I have new data of:

- Sepal.Length : 5.6
- Sepal.Width : 7.5
- Petal.Length : 7.3
- Petal.Width : 3.4

Is it possible to produce what Species is with the new data in machine learning?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is the whole point around ML and predictive modeling; I kindly suggest you have a look in the (literally, dozens) of tutorials available online, and come back here for questions about *programming*, which SO is about

Comment: Good to see a newbie on SO is welcomed. Nice gesture.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, that's the point of the model that you trained with data before.

In this case, you will get one class (or 3 probabilities, one for each class, the sum being one) for this 3-class problem and your 4 features.

Comment: But how? Because my new data only consist of 4 inputs unlike my test data which has 5 columns of data. I know we use test data on our trained model to find how accurate the model can predict but how do we use 4 new features to find out which Class it belongs to...

Comment: Your model is trained to take these 4 inputs and turn it into the 5th one. When you do the testing of the model, you do the same, you compare the result of the 4 features against the 5th column. Here, you don't have the fifth, but the confidence in the return of the model is given my the tests you have done on data that has the 5 columns.

Comment: So if I want to find which class the above features belong to, do I just have to set that 4 features as my new data and predict() with the model I built?

Comment: Right! Thanks!! :D